# Eclipse RCP XMI spies view unreadable with dark theme on Linux, any suggestions?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

Eclipse RCP dark theme XMI spies view literally unreadable

Title. Any way to fix it? Clean eclipse rcp for linux, default dark theme, no plugins installed. Deafault light theme works fine for this view, but I really like the editor in dark theme. Screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEkRC.png)

Comment: Which version? If latest version, consider to contribute a fix as pull request to the Eclipse Platform project.